# Require/import svg during mocha tests

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocha.js

I have a project being built with webpack. This allows me to import `.svg` files to create React components.

When running tests I have been attempting to avoid using webpack to avoid tying the mocha version to a webpack plugin. Unfortunately, when the `.svg` imports are hit, they fail to be found. We are also using css modules, and they allowed me to use the `css-modules-require-hook` to work around the importing of css files.

Is there a technique I could use to accomplish the same thing with SVGs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I just find a way to mock `.svg` module for `mocha` [here](https://github.com/dqisme/__react-svg-loader-bug-36).

Mocha can use `require hooks` to deal with universal javascript import, such as `babel-register` for `.js`.

You can use [require-hacker](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/require-hacker) to add hooks to extensions of modules.

You can use a null react component mock for other component loaders such as `react-svg-loader` to load `.svg` as a react component.

here is the example:

```
import requireHacker from 'require-hacker';

const fakeComponentString = `
  require('react').createClass({
    render() {
      return null;
    }
  })
`;

// for fake component
requireHacker.hook('svg', path => `module.exports = ${fakeComponentString}`);
```

Comment: Currently `require-hacker` relies on `core-js@2` which is deprecated. I'm looking for an alternative right now.

Answer (score 15):

I saw this solved by using `require.extensions` (in node this is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions), but should never go away) to force importing these types of assets to result in an no-op.  Starting `mocha` with the `--require` flag lets us configure the runtime environment for our tests so starting mocha like this:

```
NODE_PATH=./app mocha -w --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./app/lib/testHelper.js --require ./app/lib/testNullCompiler.js 'app/**/*.spec.@(js|jsx)' --watch-extensions js,jsx
```

where `testNullCompiler.js` is:

```
const noop = () => 1;

require.extensions['.css'] = noop;
require.extensions['.scss'] = noop;
require.extensions['.png'] = noop;
require.extensions['.jpg'] = noop;
require.extensions['.jpeg'] = noop;
require.extensions['.gif'] = noop;
require.extensions['.svg'] = noop;
```

This will cause all the above types of files to return the `noop` function instead of attempting to load the actual file.

My code is using the `es6` `import` syntax but I'm assuming that `babel` is converting that to `require` under the covers which enables this technique to work.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: Agreed. I liked the clean js/jsx extension syntax too.